# Why is Java Sound API frame position getting stuck?

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm trying to create a sound recorder using Java Sound API on Kotlin Desktop. I want to automatically stop the recording after 3 seconds. The frame position does initially advance but then gets stuck.

```
class VoiceRecorder {

    private val format = AudioFormat(
        AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
        16000.0F,
        16,
        1,
        2,
        16000.0F,
        false
    )

    private val info = DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine::class.java, format)
    private val line = AudioSystem.getLine(info) as TargetDataLine

    init {
        if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)) {
            println("Line is not supported!!!")
        }else{
            println("Line is supported.")
        }
    }

    fun startRecording(){

        line.open()
        line.start()

        val recordingStream = AudioInputStream(line)
        val outputFile = File("src/main/resources/record.wav")
        val frameRate = format.frameRate

    runBlocking {
        while(line.framePosition/frameRate<3.0){
            val time = line.framePosition/frameRate
            delay(100)
            println("position: ${line.framePosition}, time: $time")
        }
    }


        AudioSystem.write(recordingStream, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, outputFile)
        line.stop()
        line.close()
    }
}
```

This is output of the print statement:

```
position: 1619, time: 0.0
position: 3219, time: 0.1011875
position: 4835, time: 0.2011875
position: 6435, time: 0.3021875
position: 7999, time: 0.4021875
position: 7999, time: 0.4999375
position: 7999, time: 0.4999375
position: 7999, time: 0.4999375
goes on until you die...
```

What is causing this and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: In your while loop `line.framePosition/frameRate<3.0` what happens if `line.framePosition/frameRate` never becomes greater than `3.0`? Yes, it will loop for ever. Check that values you are getting, and work out if `<3.0` is the correct number here, or should you use less than or equal `<=3.0` to prevent an infinite loop?

Comment: @sorifiend yes, it keeps looping forever as you can see in the output of the print statement.

Comment: So, have you checked the values of `line.framePosition/frameRate` as suggested in my comment? Does it ever exceeded 3.0? If not, then you need to change your loop end condition `while(someValue < correctValue - offsetValue)`?

Comment: @sorifiend sorry, I had uploaded an old version of the code. "time: " in the print statement is line.framePosition/frameRate. Will fix.

Comment: I do not know what the value of `frameRate` is, but I imagine you are having an issue with integers vs doubles, and your calculation is resulting in an incorrect whole number. Inside your loop add some debugging so you can check what the real value is, for example `println("The current loop value is: " + line.framePosition/frameRate);` or whatever the correct format is with kotlin

Comment: @sorifiend I think what you are asking is the same as the time variable which is being printed, is it not?

Comment: Ahh right you are. So why do you use `<3.0` in the loop? Changing 3.0 to the correct value will surely solve your issue.

Comment: @sorifiend because I want to record for 3 seconds. The frame position is not supposed to stop until you call line.stop() . I have managed to make this work before on other platform like Android, but for reasons with this particular configuration it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: If you use the frame position as your loop condition and you want to record for 3 seconds but your track is less than 3 seconds long it will always fail and loop forever. You need to check that the track is long enough and that the math is correct, or I suggest using a different condition in your loop, for example create and start a timer then use, `while (timeElapsed <3.0){...`

Comment: @sorifiend I am not playing a track. I am recording one.

Comment: To be honest, I do not know how the `line` object works, but you are still using values from `line` here `line.framePosition`. You are using values from the track that is being recorded to determine how long the recording should run for, this is bound to fail and loop for ever if line has issues, or something unexpected happens as is clear in your example. You want to record for a set period of time, so your best solution is use a timer of some sort instead? I will bow out here, and let someone else help if they can. But I think you need to debug more and rethink your loop condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that AudioSystem.write needs to run in a separate coroutine.

For example, add

```
private val cr = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
```

then do

```
cr.launch { AudioSystem.write(recordingStream, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, outputFile) }

runBlocking {
    while(line.framePosition/frameRate<3.0){
        val time = line.framePosition/frameRate
        delay(100)
        println("position: ${line.framePosition}, time: $time")
    }
}
```